# How can I make my dropdown menu appear like in a box?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a menu with a dropdown and I want show it like a box, but when I use `display: flex` it shows a long list.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 10</a>
    <a href="#">Link 21</a>
    <a href="#">Link 32</a>
    <a href="#">Link 13</a>
    <a href="#">Link 24</a>
    <a href="#">Link 35</a>
    <a href="#">Link 16</a>
    <a href="#">Link 27</a>
    <a href="#">Link 38</a>
    <a href="#">Link 19</a>
    <a href="#">Link 20</a>
    <a href="#">Link 39</a>
    <a href="#">Link 18</a>
    <a href="#">Link 27</a>
    <a href="#">Link 36</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The menu list should be like this:
[image: Menu list]

How can I make look like the image?

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** to `ul` `li` instead of `button` (based on comment).

You can do something like this (modifications are noted in the CSS):

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* new */
  list-style: none;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /* new */
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  /* new */
  top: 68px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  /* new */
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}


/* bullets */

a::before {
  content: "○ ";
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul class="dropbtn">
    <li>Dropdown</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 10</a>
    <a href="#">Link 21</a>
    <a href="#">Link 32</a>
    <a href="#">Link 13</a>
    <a href="#">Link 24</a>
    <a href="#">Link 35</a>
    <a href="#">Link 16</a>
    <a href="#">Link 27</a>
    <a href="#">Link 38</a>
    <a href="#">Link 19</a>
    <a href="#">Link 20</a>
    <a href="#">Link 39</a>
    <a href="#">Link 18</a>
    <a href="#">Link 27</a>
    <a href="#">Link 36</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and if I need to use a <ul> <li> instead of a button to display de information????

Comment: Julio, I edited above to `<ul><li>`, but for future reference, please consider incorporating all desired things in the original post, thank you. Hope it helps you, regards.

Comment: I will do it next time sorry I was rush when I did the first question

Comment: No problem it happens, needless to say, if the answer helped you, please consider marking it correct, thank you Julio, regards.